# Django code changes not reflected without restart

Tags: python, django

I used `python manage.py runserver` to start the django server locally. I noticed the change of HTML code is not reflected if I don't re-start the server. Is it normal? Is it possible to see the change without restarting the server?

Update:
I saw the I am in the production env, so the `Debug` is `False`. I am wondering how can I change to Development mode?

Comment: Check your `DEBUG` value under your settings. Put it to `True` and Django will detect the changes under all your files.

Comment: @ChihebNexus Thanks! I saw I am currently in Production so the DEBUG is False. How can I change to Development?

Comment: It is not possible to change the DEBUG variable if you already have started the server with it being set to False. You must update the variable and restart the webserver for the variable to take effect. In a production envrionment you must restart your server in order for any files to be updated when changed. There is no way around it.

Comment: @Grokzen Thanks. Yes, I understand. I am asking how to start the server in Development environment. It is always in Production environment.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to create a local settings so you can work in a "development environment", so, you can have a settings.py where you set all the configuration for your production server, always with DEBUG=False, never set DEBUG=True in production.

And also, you can additionally create a local_settings.py where you change only those variables that you need to change for your development environment, like the DEBUG value, so, in your local_settings.py you can have only this:

```
# local_settings.py
DEBUG=True
```

And in your settings.py add this at the end:

```
# settings.py
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

This will override the variables you set in the local_settings when you run the development server.

Make sure you don't push this file to your server (if you're using **git** add it to your **.gitignore** file)